# Why is php gzip output not working for me?

Tags: php, compression, gzip

I have this code:

```
<?php
// Include this function on your pages
function print_gzipped_page() {

    global $HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING;
    if( headers_sent() ){
        $encoding = false;
    }elseif( strpos($HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING, 'x-gzip') !== false ){
        $encoding = 'x-gzip';
    }elseif( strpos($HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING,'gzip') !== false ){
        $encoding = 'gzip';
    }else{
        $encoding = false;
    }

    if( $encoding ){
        $contents = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        header('Content-Encoding: '.$encoding);
        print("\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00");
        $size = strlen($contents);
        $contents = gzcompress($contents, 9);
        $contents = substr($contents, 0, $size);
        print($contents);
        exit();
    }else{
        ob_end_flush();
        exit();
    }
}

// At the beginning of each page call these two functions
ob_start();
ob_implicit_flush(0);

// Then do everything you want to do on the page
?>
<html>
<body>
<p>This should be a compressed page.</p>
</html>
<body>
<?

// Call this function to output everything as gzipped content.
print_gzipped_page();
?>
```

But when i view the page source, I'm not seeing compressed code. WHat's wrong?

Comment: The browser automatically decompresses the html, and shows that to the user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> WHat's wrong?

probably nothing. GZIP compression is a completely transparent process between the server and the browser. The server will compress, and the browser will automatically uncompress the data. In the end result (= the HTML page's source code), nothing will change.

Use tools like Firebug or Chrome's developer tools to see whether the response was actually compressed.

In Chrome's Developer tools' "Network" tab, a compressed response will look something like this:

http://fhc.quickmediasolutions.com/image/-1775578843.png

Comment: Oh, ok. Now I know! How do I check this out in Chrome's element inspector?

Comment: @trusktr Go to the "Network" tab, go to the resource in question, open the "headers" tab and look for the response headers shown above. Updated my answer with a screen shot.

Comment: Thanks! I see it now! oh yeah, that's nice. The transfer went from 65kb to 3.5 kb.

Comment: @trusktr I'm not sure whether that's always the uncompressed size. Firefox's Web Developer toolbar has a "Document size" overview in the "Information" menu that shows the compressed and uncompressed sizes.

Comment: I was guessing so because when I removed the gzip compression, the transfer size equaled the content size, then re-enabling it the transfer size went back down... Yeah, firefox also shows the same (firebug).

Answer (score 1):

When viewing the source code in the browser, you'll always see the decompressed version.

Answer (score 1):

using apache mod_deflate is much more effective and comfortable… http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html

Comment: Cool, it works, but I don't really see what's better. The file sizes seem the same. Why is mod_defalte better?

Comment: Oh, yeah, i mean compared to my code above, yeah. hehe... but all Ihad to do was put `` in the htaccess and that was pretty easy... But then again, using what you linked to also compressed everything else... Nice. :D

Comment: its much less redundancy. you also could compress assets (like js, css, images and so on). its less memory consuming (u may know that the memory management of php isn't that good)

Comment: Cool good to know. So far I've gotten everything compressed except images. It doesn't seem to be compressing any of them. Can you provide a live example?

Answer (score 1):

As a side tip: On a mobile I noticed that gzip wasn't working on some assets to finally discover that the assets were in application cache, so they weren't being retrieved from the server at all. Unfortunately Chrome audits isn't yet smart enough to know that cached assets don't need to be compressed and reports them as problems.

Answer (score -1):

**Maybe this might help.**

```
<?php
function gzip_output() {
$HTTP_ACCEPT = $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'];

if (headers_sent()) {
    $encoding = false;
} elseif (strpos($HTTP_ACCEPT, 'x-gzip') !== false) {
    $encoding = 'x-gzip';
} elseif (strpos($HTTP_ACCEPT, 'gzip') !== false) {
    $encoding = 'gzip';
} else {
    $encoding = false;
}

if ($encoding) {
    $contents = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    header('Content-Encoding: ' . $encoding);
    print("\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00");
    $size = strlen($contents);
    $contents = gzcompress($contents, 9);
    $contents = substr($contents, 0, $size);
    echo $contents;
    exit();
  } else {
     ob_end_flush();
     exit();
  }
}
  // At the beginning of each page call these two functions
  ob_start();
 ob_implicit_flush(0);

 // Then do everything you want to do on the page
 ?>
 <html>
 <body>
 <p>This should be a compressed page.</p>
  </html>
  <body>
  <?

// Call this function to output everything as gzipped content.
gzip_output();
?>
```